# How to convert a Java 8 Stream into a two dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I’m trying to convert a map based `Stream` into a two-dimensional array. I have figured out how to store it in a one dimensional array. Here is working code snippet:

```
Float[] floatArray = map.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(key -> key.getKey().getPrice())
                        .toArray(size -> new Float[size]);
```

When I execute the above code, I get my `Float` array populated as expected. Now I need to extend this to a two-dimensional array where I need to store the result in first dimension of a 2d array along these lines:

```
Float[][1] floatArray = map.entrySet()
                           .stream()
                           .map(key -> key.getKey().getPrice())
                           .toArray(size -> new Float[size][1]);
```

The code above does not work. Can you please let me know how to accomplish this task with Java 8 streams? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "convert and map based stream to a two-dimensional array" - please post a (small) example of such map and how is the 2D array supposed to look like (expected output).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at `<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)`, you see that it converts a `Stream<A>` to a `A[]`, which is a 1D array of `A` elements. So in order for it to create a 2D array, the elements of the `Stream` must be arrays.

Therefore you can create a 2D array if you first `map` the elements of your `Stream` to a 1D array and then call `toArray`:

```
Float[][] floatArray = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .map(key -> new Float[]{key.getKey().getPrice()})
       .toArray(size -> new Float[size][1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! My next question is if I want to populate three dimensions of my floatArray from the map for instance:   Float[][] floatArray = 
       map.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(key -> new Float[]{key.getKey().getPrice()},{key.getKey().getOpen()},{key.getKey().getClose()})
          .toArray(size -> new Float[size][3]); How can this be accomplished?

Comment: I want to be able to first populate all three dimensions/columns of my 2D floatArray from map entries and then loop through the floatArray later in the code to perform downstream calculations using floatArray like so: for (int i=0; i<floatArray.rows; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<floatArray.cols; j++) {
    //do some calcs here
   someCalc = floatArray[i][j] * 2; 
  }

Comment: One last request, in the third column of floatArray, I want to store the counter for example if there are 10 entries in the map, I want to store value 1...10 in third column. Thanks

Comment: I was able to figure out how to populate multiple dimensions: Float[][] floatArray = 
       map.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(key -> new Float[]{(float) 0.00,key.getKey().getPrice(),(float) 0.00})
          .toArray(size -> new Float[size][3]); The only thing left is to add a counter in the first position or how to replace (float) 0.00 in position 1 with a counter. Thanks

Comment: @MazS that's still a 2D array, not 3D. If that's what you wanted, your comment about "three dimensions" was confusing.

Comment: Like so often, the OP failed to make the right choice between `keySet()` and `entrySet()`. The code would be much simpler using the right view: `Float[][] floatArray = map.keySet() .stream() .map(key -> new Float[]{key.getPrice()}) .toArray(Float[][]::new);`

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of the following:

```
Float[][] array = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .map(YourKeyClass::getPrice) // 1)
    .map(price -> new Float[]{ price })
    .toArray(Float[][]::new);
```

Which creates a 2D array just like you expected.

**Note:** By the comment *1)* you have to replace `YourKeyClass` with the class containing the method `getPrice()` returning a `Float` object.

---

An alternative is also to use `.keySet()` instead of `.entrySet()`:

```
Float[][] array = map.keySet().stream()
    .map(YourKeyClass::getPrice)
    .map(price -> new Float[]{price})
    .toArray(Float[][]::new);
```