# Map to 2d array with Streams

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, java-stream

I am trying to create a 2d array of `String` using Streams:

```
String[] fruit1DArray;
String[][] fruit2DArray;

Map<String, String> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();
fruitMap.put("apple", "red");
fruitMap.put("pear", "green");
fruitMap.put("orange", "orange");

fruit1DArray = fruitMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(key -> key.getKey())
    .toArray(size -> new String[size]);

fruit2DArray = fruitMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry-> new String[]{entry.getKey()})
    .toArray(size -> new String[size][1]);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(fruit1DArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(fruit2DArray));
```

The output is:

```
[orange, apple, pear]
[[orange], [apple], [pear]]
```

The output I am after is:

```
[orange, apple, pear]
[[orange, orange], [apple, red], [pear, green]]
```

I am referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397601/887235

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to grab the value from your input `Map`:

```
fruit2DArray = fruitMap.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .map(e -> new String[]{e.getKey(),e.getValue()})
                       .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Output:

```
[[orange, orange], [apple, red], [pear, green]]
```

Comment: Time to fix [the already linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397601/2711488) to similarly use `.toArray(Float[][]::new);` instead of `.toArray(size -> new Float[size][1]);` which wastes performance populating the new array with subarrays which are overwritten afterwards.